# Scriptella feature request on onerror: connection-id

Tags: scriptella

This is a feature request, from link below seems like no other workaround yet but to do the operation in the current connection in the context:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/scriptella/BpfD6BJc804

Is it possible to support 'connection-id' in 'onerror' tag? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** The feature has been implemented and it will be included into 1.2 release. Current development snapshot can be download from here: http://javaforge.com/displayDocument/scriptella-1.2-SNAPSHOT.zip?doc_id=222665

---

I've created a [change request](http://javaforge.com/issue/54586) and will consider adding this feature in future releases.

Regarding the workaround. Why is it not acceptable?

Comment: Will vote for the answer once implemented ;) I think nobody said workaround is not accepted, but rather its not always comfortable in using the workaround

Comment: I asked about the workaround to have a better understanding of importance of the feature. As I see, in most of the cases an error can be handled by executing the alternative statement in the same connection.

Comment: hi ejboy, for my case the workaround is a not so comfortable workaround. I had to convert my connection to java just to achieve what I need. My problem was v similar to the google post above. Thanks

Comment: The feature has been implemented. Your move ;)